# Templating using Spring El expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I would like using spring el for simple templating like `"Some text: #{some dynamic value from map}"`. In my case, examples from [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-properties-arrays) doesn't fit, because it work only for value form map:

```
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("property", 123);

    String message = "#data['property']";

    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.setVariable("data", data);

    System.out.println(parser.parseExpression(message).getValue(context, String.class));
```

In this case output is `123`, but `String message = "Some text: #data['property']";` created exception

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 5): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'text'
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:129)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:60)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SpelExpressionParser.java:32)
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:76)
at org.springframework.expression.common.TemplateAwareExpressionParser.parseExpression(TemplateAwareExpressionParser.java:62)
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text needs to be a literal.

What you have now would look like this in java...

```
String s = some text: data.get("property");
```

... which obviously wouldn't compile.

If you were writing it in java, you'd need to use...

```
String s = "some text: " + data.get("property");
```

...so you need to use the equivalent in SpEL...

```
"'Some text: ' + #data['property']"
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you might want to use `TemplateParserContext` mentioned in [Expression templating](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-templating). Your example then would look as follows:

```
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("property", 123);

        String message = "Some text: #{#data['property']}";

        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        Expression expression = parser.parseExpression(message, new TemplateParserContext());
        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.setVariable("data", data);

        System.out.println(expression.getValue(context,String.class));
```